# Non-Noetherian module which is not a ring

Tags: ring-theory, vector-spaces, modules

I was thinking about the following question:

> Find a non-Noetherian module which is not a ring.

All the examples I have in mind can be thought as rings. For instance, one can take the space of real sequences $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R}$. It is indeed an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space which is infinite dimensional and hence not Noetherian. However it is also a ring, and it is not Noetherian also as a ring.

I was thinking of something similar to this: an infinite-dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb{k}$, but where I cannot put the structure of a ring. I tried spaces of functions like $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ or Lebesgue spaces of functions $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, but here too, since I can multiply functions, it still makes this a ring.

Comment: If $F$ is a field then $F[x]$ is Noetherian as a ring, but not as a module over $F$. Not sure if that's the example you are looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Example of a Noetherian module that is not a ring?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173210/example-of-a-noetherian-module-that-is-not-a-ring)

Comment: @Sebastiano no, I have seen it but it is not what I am searching for. I need something which cannot be thought also as a ring.

Comment: @Mark yes but $F[x]$ can also be fought as a ring, as you said. I need something which is a module and cannot be thought also as a ring. As I wrote, it is clear that when you have a field $\mathbb{k}$ and an infinite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{k}$ (like $\mathbb{k}[x]$) you have something which is a $\mathbb{k}$-vector space which is not Noetherian, but I need something which cannot really be thought as a ring.

Comment: What do you mean with "cannot really be thought as a ring"? _any_ set can be equipped with a ring structure in _some_ way.

Comment: @student91 I don't really see it for uncountable sets. Care to explain?

Comment: @DarioAntolini If $\kappa$ is any infinite cardinality then the direct sum of $\kappa$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring of cardinality $\kappa$. So indeed any nonempty set can be given a structure of a ring. (given the axiom of choice)

Comment: @Mark okay thanks. You are right.

Comment: What is the point of disallowing it to be a ring?  It's sort of like asking "show me a penguin, but not one born in July."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, every set $S$ can be thought as a ring. Just consider:
$$ \bigoplus_{s \in S} \mathbb{Z} $$

So the only possible answer to the question is to find a set which is only equipped with a module structure which is not a ring structure and such that it is not Noetherian. As already pointed out by myself, one can search within infinite dimensional vector spaces. For instance, as suggested by @Mark in the answers, if $\mathbb{k}$ is a field, $\mathbb{k}[x]$ is an infinite dimensional vector space, which is hence not Noetherian.